# Find a basis for the given subspace in $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a tough time figuring out where to begin with this problem:

Find a basis for the given subspace in $\Bbb R^4$: the set of all vectors of the form

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a + c \\
        a - b \\
        b + c \\
        -a + b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Write your matrix as a sum of three vectors. First vector that only contains $a$, second vector that only contains $b$, third vector that only contains $c$. What happens if you put these letters as scalars upfront of each vector?

Comment: Wow....  I knew it was something simple, just not quite that simple.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your vector and it consists of three different variables, suggesting you're going to probably $3$ vectors to span this. Notice that it is in the form of a general equation. How can you write the variables $a, b, c$ in terms of some basis? What basis is the easiest to pick?

**Note:** Basis of the coefficients of equations in the vector is the first choice
$$        \begin{bmatrix}
        a + c \\
        a - b \\
        b + c \\
        -a + b \\
        \end{bmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Verify this solution by expressing the vector in a system of equations.